# Rolling upgrades in YugaByte DB - is it possible?

Tags: database, distributed-database, yugabytedb

Does YugaByte DB have the ability to support rolling upgrades for the system?

Answer (score 2):

For software rolling upgrades, please view https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/manage/upgrade-deployment/ for the suggested steps.